# How do I both sum 1 table and combine that result with another?

Tags: sql, oracle

I'm using Oracle SQL and I have two tables:

```
Employee:
VARCHAR  VARCHAR
EMP_NUM EMP_NAME
------- --------
1       Jane    
1       Jane    
1       Jane    
1       Jane    
2       Alex    
2       Alex    
2       Alex    
3       Danny   
3       Danny   

Assignment:
    NUMBER        FLOAT         FLOAT VARCHAR
ASSIGN_NUM ASSIGN_HOURS ASSIGN_CHARGE EMP_NUM
---------- ------------ ------------- -------
         1          3.5           290 1
         2          2.6          68.2 3
         3            2           406 3
         4          4.7           541 2
         5          3.3            76 1
```

and I need to combine them into something like this:

```
TempTable:
VARCHAR  VARCHAR     FLOAT      FLOAT
EMP_NUM EMP_NAME SUM_HOURS SUM_CHARGE
------- -------- --------- ----------
1       Jane          27.2       1464
2       Alex          14.1       1623
3       Danny          9.2      948.4
```

I've tried using this, but it doesn't work:

```
SELECT
    Assignment.EMP_NUM,
    Employee.EMP_NAME,
    SUM(Assignment.ASSIGN_HOURS) SUM_HOURS,
    SUM(Assignment.ASSIGN_CHARGE) SUM_CHARGE
  FROM Employee, Assignment
    WHERE Employee.EMP_NUM = Assignment.EMP_NUM
  GROUP BY Assignment.EMP_NUM
;
```

But SQL complains with:

```
Error starting at line 1 in command:
SELECT
    Assignment.EMP_NUM,
    Employee.EMP_NAME,
    SUM(Assignment.ASSIGN_HOURS) SUM_HOURS,
    SUM(Assignment.ASSIGN_CHARGE) SUM_CHARGE
  FROM Employee, Assignment
    WHERE Employee.EMP_NUM = Assignment.EMP_NUM
  GROUP BY Assignment.EMP_NUM
Error at Command Line:3 Column:5
Error report:
SQL Error: ORA-00979: not a GROUP BY expression
00979. 00000 -  "not a GROUP BY expression"
*Cause:    
*Action:
```

Even if I remove the `GROUP BY` line, I get an error at `Line:2 Column:5` saying `not a single-group group function`. **Is there any way to get this table**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The query should be like this, you need to list all fields in SELECT clause:

```
SELECT
    Assignment.EMP_NUM,
    Employee.EMP_LNAME,
    SUM(Assignment.ASSIGN_HOURS) SUM_HOURS,
    SUM(Assignment.ASSIGN_CHARGE) SUM_CHARGE
  FROM Employee, Assignment
    WHERE Employee.EMP_NUM = Assignment.EMP_NUM
  GROUP BY Assignment.EMP_NUM, 
           Employee.EMP_LNAME
;
```

Comment: Wow... photo finish there. I'll give it to you because yours is a more generally useful answer.

Answer (score 1):

You forgot to include `Employee.EMP_LNAME` in your `GROUP BY` clause.

Code should be:

```
SELECT
    Assignment.EMP_NUM,
    Employee.EMP_LNAME,
    SUM(Assignment.ASSIGN_HOURS) SUM_HOURS,
    SUM(Assignment.ASSIGN_CHARGE) SUM_CHARGE
  FROM Employee, Assignment
    WHERE Employee.EMP_NUM = Assignment.EMP_NUM
  GROUP BY Assignment.EMP_NUM, Employee.EMP_LNAME
```

Comment: Wow... photo finish there. Though yours points out my specific error, I'll give it to @MinhD because theirs is a more generally useful answer.

Answer (score 1):

You need to do the aggregations before you do the joins, otherwise, your numbers will be incorrect:

```
SELECT e.EMP_NUM, e.EMP_LNAME, a.SUM_HOURS, SUM_CHARGE
FROM (SELECT DISTINCT e.EMP_NUM, e.EMP_LNAME FROM Employee e) e join
     (SELECT a.EMP_NUM,
             SUM(Assignment.ASSIGN_HOURS) as SUM_HOURS,
             SUM(Assignment.ASSIGN_CHARGE) as SUM_CHARGE
      FROM Assignment a
      GROUP BY a.EMP_NUM
     ) a
     on e.EMP_NUM = a.EMP_NUM;
```

I also changed the join syntax to use explicit joins.

Comment: Uh... what? I'm sorry, I don't understand... and the other answers solved it

Comment: @Supuhstar . . . Based on the sample data in the question, the other answers will produce incorrect results.  For instance, Alex should produce 3*541 = 1623 instead of 541.

Comment: I understand what you're saying, but the result matches up with my sample result perfectly.  +1 for pointing this out and writing a more production-quality select statement though

Comment: actually I think I made a mistake. it _should_ be 1623 instead of 541 ^^;

Comment: @Supuhstar . . . It seems very curious to me that you would be multiplying reported numbers by the number of rows in another table.  Of course, having duplicates in the employees table doesn't make sense either.

Comment: there is more data in the actual tables, but I didn't make them, so... yeah :/ it is weird